# Synaptics Touchpad Signature

Tags: c#, mouseevent, mouse

I want to use the Synaptics SDK to use the Touchpad to capture a signature.  I am trying to capture the absolute X and Y positions of the touch so that I can track people lifting their finger and putting it down somewhere else.  I know that I'm able to access the Touchpad because I can disable it and access the dimensions of the Touchpad.

The next step would be to get the absolute X and Y coordinates.  According to the [Synaptics PS/2 TouchPad Interfacing Guide](http://www.synaptics.com/sites/default/files/511-000275-01_RevB.pdf) (page 22) there is an "Absolute Mode" where I can get this information.  So far I can't seem to access it.  I don't know how to set it to that mode.

I'm developing in Visual Studio Express 2012 using C#.

Also, I can't seem to activate any of the events whatsoever.  I'm trying to register the events like this:

```
using SYNCOMLib;
using SYNCTRLLib;

SYNCTRLLib.SynAPICtrl SynAPICtrl1 = new SynAPICtrl();
SYNCTRLLib.SynDeviceCtrl SynDeviceCtrl1 = new SynDeviceCtrl();
SYNCTRLLib.SynDisplayCtrl SynDisplayCtrl1 = new SynDisplayCtrl();

SynAPICtrl1.OnNotify += SynAPICtrl1_OnNotify;
SynDeviceCtrl1.OnPacket += SynDeviceCtrl1_OnPacket;
SynDisplayCtrl1.OnMessage += SynDisplayCtrl1_OnMessage;
```

I have functions which just log the function name to the console:

```
private void SynDisplayCtrl1_OnMessage(SynDisplayMessage eMessage)
{
    Console.WriteLine("SynDisplayCtrl1_OnMessage");
}

private void SynAPICtrl1_OnNotify(SynNotificationReason eReason)
{
    Console.WriteLine("SynAPICtrl1_OnNotify");
}

private void SynDeviceCtrl1_OnPacket()
{
    Console.WriteLine("SynDeviceCtrl1_OnPacket");
}
```

None of these functions ever get called (or at least nothing ever gets logged in the console).  I'm fairly new to Visual Studio and C#, so the solution may be a very simple fix.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**  Here's the link to the [Synaptics SDK](http://www.synaptics.com/sites/default/files/SynCOMAPIv1_0.zip) in case you want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the info on [this site](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/65849-controlling-synaptics-touchpad-using-com-api/) and converted it into the following C#.

At the top of my code:

```
using SYNCOMLib;
using SYNCTRLLib;
```

Outside of my functions so they're global

```
SynAPICtrl SynTP_API = new SynAPICtrl();
SynDeviceCtrl SynTP_Dev = new SynDeviceCtrl();
SynPacketCtrl SynTP_Pack = new SynPacketCtrl();
int DeviceHandle;
```

Inside my constructor

```
SynTP_API.Initialize();
SynTP_API.Activate();
DeviceHandle = SynTP_API.FindDevice(new SynConnectionType(), new SynDeviceType(), 0);
SynTP_Dev.Select(DeviceHandle);
SynTP_Dev.Activate();  
SynTP_Dev.OnPacket += SynTP_Dev_OnPacket;
```

Finally, the function to handle the event

```
private void SynTP_Dev_OnPacket()
{
    if (SynTP_Dev.LoadPacket(SynTP_Pack) == 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(SynTP_Pack.FingerState);
        Console.WriteLine(SynTP_Pack.X);
        Console.WriteLine(SynTP_Pack.Y);
    }
}
```

I'm going to change some variable names to make them a bit more intuitive, but this code works just fine.

Comment: I have SynTP_Pack.X, SynTP_Pack.Y equal to 0. Every time I touch the touch pad

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer does not work on Windows 10. Here is a corrected code sample that demonstrates detecting a 3-finger tap on the trackpad. The same method of detecting absolute coordinates in the accepted answer could work here too - but note loadPacket() would always return 0, rather than 1.

Note: the gestures you want to detect must be enabled in the Synaptics control panel. Also, since the Synaptics SDK appears to have been taken offline, I was able to directly reference C:\Windows\System32\SynCom.dll from .NET.

```
class Program
{
    static SynAPICtrl api = new SynAPICtrl();
    static SynDeviceCtrl device = new SynDeviceCtrl();
    static SynPacketCtrl packet = new SynPacketCtrl();
    static int deviceHandle;
    static int counter;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {   
        api.Initialize();
        api.Activate();
        //select the first device found
        deviceHandle = api.FindDevice(SynConnectionType.SE_ConnectionAny, SynDeviceType.SE_DeviceTouchPad, -1);
        device.Select(deviceHandle);
        device.Activate();
        device.OnPacket += SynTP_Dev_OnPacket;
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static private void SynTP_Dev_OnPacket()
    {
        var result = device.LoadPacket(packet);
        SynFingerFlags fingerState;
        if(Enum.TryParse(packet.FingerState.ToString(), out fingerState))
        {
            if(fingerState.HasFlag(SynFingerFlags.SF_FingerTap3))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Tapped {counter++}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I counldn't find SynCom.dll under system32 folder. Is there a website which I can download it from?

Comment: I've found interop.syncomlib.dll and interop.synctrllib.dll added them to test project but I'm getting error on new SynAPICtrl(),  :  "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered"

Comment: @AntiqTech I had the same problem and was able to solve it by running it on a machine with Synaptics hardware and installed drivers.

Comment: thanks for suggestion but I stopped working on that awhile ago. I'll keep this in mind If I get back to it.